# C++/CMake: How to find places where the copy constructor is invoked

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class with a copy constructor. I would like to identify all places where the copy constructor is invoked. One way, I could think of is to delete the copy constructor and rebuilt the entire project to identify it. But I would like to know is there any other way to find it out, instead of rebuilding the entire project.
I use CMake to build the projects.

Comment: Note that calls to the copy constructor may not be limited to your own code base. If you use something like `std::vector`, **it** might call the copy constructor. You could have a look at stack backtracing and just dump a line to standard out from within the constructor. Then run the program. It will show all calls encountered **during that particular run**.

Answer (score 1):

With an IDE like Visual Studio you might be lucky and the IDE would spot all the errors. But internally, the IDE just builds your project in the background. So you would not win much.

CMake is of no help here, you have to rebuild the project anyway. All CMake helps is that it identifies which files need to be rebuild after you deleted the copy constructor. Maybe only a couple of files really include the file with your C++ class and only they must be rebuilt.